# PHP created infinite loop by accident?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Background Info - I created a online shop a while ago dropshipping products i created the website and added all product info by hand. Now i have knowledge in php i created a scraper/spider to get all the required info i need without doing anything by hand

Question - My script runs on my local server collecting all links from the sites sitemap.xml this is uploaded to my database once this script is complete it starts going through the links extracting the data needed Picture, Price, Name, Desc etc... the site i am scraping is not happy that i am doing it due to human/computer errors that can only be spotted by a human, but have allowed it. anyway my script sometimes throws me an error when a item cannot be scraped due to some unknown reasons so i have put a die() when the script throws this error.

This is placed inside the mysql while loop for the links, i have noticed a few times that when an error does occur the script stops loading shows me the exact error, but when i shut down the browser it carries on deleting queries and extracting information i need to manually restart the server before it stops.

How is this possible and what can i do to prevent this? is it the die() statement just kills the client side script and keeps the server side script running ?

Comment: can we see some sanitised code?

Comment: die() in client-side code? there is no 'die' in javascript. If you do `die()` in a php script, it just quits. there is no "continuing".

Answer (score 0):

So you are running PHP locally to gather data from a remote site. You start a PHP script in your local browser. And the script does not stop when the browser is closed.

Of course the local server must be stopped.

However I think PHP can also be run from the command line (maybe only Linux?) and then output could go to the command line, and the command line might be simply killed.

Another solution is: in the loops checking for the (non-)existence of a file and then die. A second PHP script, callable in a second browser tab, then adds/removes that signal file.

(The file might serve as a lock too, so you do not start the data gathering twice.)

Comment: Windows also supports PHP Cli, I don't know why it shouldn't ;)

Comment: @ComFreek I heard from the CLI from the Linux side, so was not certain.